# How to make Rails 3 app and Wordpress blog work on same domain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress

The rails app is hosted on rackspace cloud server and the wp blog is hosted on bluehost. I've created a subdomain blog.domain.com for the wordpress blog and pointed the rails app to the domain.com. The problem is that the old blog links such as domain.com/article-name don't work anymore since old links now look at the rails app. There are a few hundred posts within the wp install, what's the best way to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

Did you solve this? I did a similar switch/set up. I do not know if this is the best solution but I used the routes.rb file to redirect the old posts to the new URL.

For pages off the root domain like your example I had manually redirect.

For things like parent pages or tags I used

```
match "/stories/:name" => redirect("/posts/%{name}")
```

I'm new to Rails and Wordpress so there may be a better way.